# Why can't I call a method I defined in a class inside that class

Tags: java, arrays, class, methods, return

*I am trying to make a palindrome finder class by using an ArrayStack. I have pretty much figured out how to do it, but I wanted to know why I cannot call my popStr() method inside the class. The code is provided below:*

```
public class PalindromeFinder{

  private static StackInt<Character> pCheck = new ArrayStack<>();
  private static String pString;
  private static String verifyString;

  public PalindromeFinder(String pString){
    PalindromeFinder.pushStr(pString.toLowerCase());
    PalindromeFinder.verifyString = pString.popStr();
  }

  public static void pushStr(String pushString){
   for (int i = 0; i < pushString.length(); i++){
     char ch = pushString.charAt(i);
     pCheck.push(ch);
   }
  }

  public static String popStr(){
    while (!pCheck.empty()){
       verifyString += pCheck.pop();
    }
    return verifyString;
  }

  public boolean palindromeCheck(String popStr){
   return popStr.equals(pString);
  }
}
```

*The line that reads 'PalindromeFinder.verifyString = pString.popStr();' gives me an error saying 'Cannot find symbol. Symbol: method popStr(); location: variable pString of type String.' Does anyone know why this is happening? I just want to be able to get the returned value of popStr() and use it in a boolean statement to determine if pString and verifyString are equal.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following line is incorrect:

```
PalindromeFinder.verifyString = pString.popStr();
```

`pString` is a `String` so you cannot call the method `popStr()` on it. (`popStr()` is not a method that is defined on the `String` class. It's one of your methods.)

Comment: Thank you. Very silly mistake on my part. I appreciate the correction!

Answer (score 0):

use

```
PalindromeFinder.verifyString = popStr();
```

insted of

```
PalindromeFinder.verifyString = pString.popStr();
```

Comment: "popStr"  is a method created in same class. then you can directly call the method

Answer (score 0):

Change your constructor, you can directly call the method `popStr()`

```
public PalindromeFinder(String pString){
    PalindromeFinder.pushStr(pString.toLowerCase());
    PalindromeFinder.verifyString = popStr();
}
```

Besides this it does not make sense to me to declare all methods and instance variable as static in the class (Defeats the purpose of OOP). If for some reason you do, then beware that all instances of your class will share the variables which may cause data loss, if for example you declare two instances.

```
PalindromeFinder p1=new PalindromeFinder("some string 1");
PalindromeFinder p2=new PalindromeFinder("some string 2"); //data given by p1 is now lost since the variable that stores the passed parameter is static in the class and is overwritten by value in p2.
```

Comment: Thanks, so you're saying that by making all methods and instances static that if I make multiple palindromeFinder objects the instance variables of the objects will override each other?

Comment: The instance variables won't override each other, but static variables and methods are present at class level. Which means however many instances you create, there will always be one copy of a static variable available at the class level, and that basically is the idea of static keyword. Hence creating new instances and referring to the variables will cause all instances to share them. You can remove the static keyword from all variables and methods, and your program should work fine (with minor changes like removing CLASS_NAME.STATIC_METHOD calls and replacing them with normal method calls)

Comment: Use static when either there is no requirement of instance creation , for example utility methods with output dependent only on the parameters (like utility methods from `Math` class) Or for example if you want to share a common (global) variable between all instances, like for example a instance counter, which counts the number of instances created.